# Cast custom collection to implemented interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

In the following, why Todos1 works, but Todos2 not? How to make it work?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _todos = new CustomCollection<Todo>();
    }

    private static CustomCollection<Todo> _todos;

    public static IEnumerable<ITodo> Todos1
    {
        get { return _todos; }
    }

    public static ICustomCollection<ITodo> Todos2
    {
        get { return _todos; }
    }

    public class CustomCollection<T> : Collection<T>, ICustomCollection<T>
    {
    }

    public interface ICustomCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
    }

    public interface ITodo
    {
    }

    public class Todo : ITodo
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how variance works; `IEnumerable<T>` is actually `IEnumerable<out T>`, meaning it is *covariant*; this meant that anything that is `IEnumerable<Todo>` is also `IEnumerable<ITodo>`, because any `Todo` is an `ITodo`.

However, collections / lists / etc are *not* covariant (or contravariant); so there is no implicit castability here. The reason being:

- you have a `CustomCollection<Todo>`
- if that was castable to `CustomCollection<ITodo>`, you could `Add` *any* `ITodo`
- including `class SomethingElse : ITodo` which is **not** a `Todo`
- so you'd have a non-`Todo` in your collection of `Todo`s

The compiler is protecting you!

Comment: So, it must be `interface ICustomCollection<out T> : IEnumerable<T>` to work; right?

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your `ICustomCollection<T>` interface as [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

```cs
public interface ICustomCollection<out T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
}
```

Otherwise it's invariant and you can cast it only to the same `Todo` type, which was used for declaration, not the `ITodo` interface.

`IEnumerable<T>` already has the covariant generic type parameter `T`, therefore the first property works as expected.